# changing <td> background color based on dynamic value, using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, json

I would like to change the background color of my systems's status. For example if it online return td background color green, offline red, else orange. I am using for loop (dynamic json array from url) so my results are not static, the system might be online now then offline after hour.
So this is my code, script:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>

  $(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
      url: 'http://localhost/api/job/',
      dataType: 'JSON',
      success: function (data) {
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
          $(document).ready(function () {
            var content = ''
            data.forEach(item => {
              content += "<tr><td class='" + item.system_status.toLowerCase() + "'>" + item.system_status + "</td></tr>"
              if (item.system_status.toLowerCase().indexOf('online') === 0) {
               
              } else if (item.system_status.toLowerCase().indexOf('offline') === 0) {
               
              } else if (item.system_status.toLowerCase().indexOf('down') === 0) {
                
              }

            })


            $('#table_body').html(content);
          })

        }
      }
    });
  });
</script>
```

and this is my html:

```
<style>
td.online {
            background-color: #a4bc31;
        }

        td.offline {
            background-color: #bc3131;
        }

        td.down {
            background-color: yellow;
        }

</style>
</body>
<table>
 
  <tbody id='table_body'></tbody>



</table>
```

what I am doing wrong??

and it is still the same, only the online and the offline is colored.

Comment: So you want to do it in javascript? hope you know that you can achieve this with normal PHP and HTML as well,
Are you receiving the above response/ array in javascript or directly in view via PHP ?

Comment: It does not really matter what method to use. Since I am using django I though javascript whould work better. but if PHP would work too please show me how to do it. thank you

Comment: What fullfills the condition between online - offline?

Comment: You just want to set the background color for `<td>` tag right?

Comment: yes. based on the array.

Comment: @Teemu I used django serializers to achieve this API. It very long, I can't post it.

Comment: You can try all three answers below. I'm pretty sure you'll find a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the below method to add `background-color` to the cells contains the status of system.

Add a class name to the cell while appending the same to DOM, and change the background-color using the same class name.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/api/job/",
    dataType: "JSON",
    success: function (data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
          var content = "";
          data.forEach((item) => {
            var class_name = "";
            if (item.system_status.toLowerCase().indexOf("online") === 0) {
              class_name = "online";
            } else if (
              item.system_status.toLowerCase().indexOf("offline") === 0
            ) {
              class_name = "offline";
            } else if (item.system_status.toLowerCase().indexOf("down") === 0) {
              class_name = "down";
            }
            content +=
              "<tr><td class='" +
              class_name +
              "'>" +
              item.system_status +
              "</td></tr>";
          });

          $("#table_body").html(content);
        });
      }
    },
  });
});
```

```css
table, td {
  border: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td.online, td.offline, td.down {
  color: #fff;
}

td.online {
  background-color: green;
}

td.offline {
  background-color: orange;
}

td.down {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tbody id='table_body'></tbody>
</table>
```

**EDIT**

Have updated the HTML the way response is received and DOM is updated.

**EDIT-2**

I have added another array called `status`. Once you receive the response data from API, you can check the received status with the `status` array, as follows:

```
status[data.system_status]
```

So it will return the corresponding class name.

**EDIT-3**

Since there are lots of possibilities that a status can be, we are planning on a `if-else` condition, as follows:

```
if(data.system_status.toLowerCase().indexOf('online') === 0) {
// Add class 'online' to the cell
} else if(data.system_status.toLowerCase().indexOf('offline') === 0) {
    // Add class 'offline' to the cell
} else if(data.system_status.toLowerCase().indexOf('down') === 0) {
    // Add class 'down' to the cell
}
```

**EDIT-4**

Updated the answer based on the update in the question snippet

Comment: Abin Thaha, thank you very much for your help. Can I use this with dynamic json array pulled from a url?? As I mentioned before, I used django rest frame work for my api, so the array data are not static. for example, this could be the data for now  {
    system_name: "1",
    system_status: "OFFLINE",
  }, and after 3 hourse it could be this {
    system_name: "1",
    system_status: "ONLINE",
  },

Comment: Yes, you can. The data will be fetched using an API and you will be appending it to the DOM using JS/jQuery right. At the time, you can use my method to add a class name to the `td`, and use css to change the background-color of the td

Comment: Thank you again, actually to fetch the data I used a view method from django, I did not use JS/jQuery. this is my code : def show(request):
    response=requests.get('http://localhost:8000/api/job/').json ()
    return render(request, 'homepage.html', {'response':response})

Comment: @leethunder, check the snippet now. Like that you can add the class name and use the css to change the bg color

Comment: Thank you Abin Thaha for your help. It did not work, T_T but thank you really

Comment: :( , why ? Has the class names being added to Dom ?>

Comment: I am not quite expert in web development. What do you mean by adding the class names to Dom? maybe this is what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Can you check click `inspect element` and check if the classes are applied to the table rows? I am no expert in django too :(. SO I am not sure about the syntax. But once if the class got applied to the cell, it would work. It must. That;s what I asked you to check in the inspect element

Comment: thank you very much, I changed the way I pull the json array to pull it using ajax and the previous code worked. But I have a question, one of the status return inconsistent results. For example, the down status return different results every time, one time the system status will be "DOWN: system over heating", other time will be "DOWN: system low battery" and so on. It is never consistent like ONLINE and OFFLINE, hence I was not able to color the down status. Any tips on how I can do that?

Comment: You can create an array of possible outcomes and add a class to the td by comparing your status with the one in the array.

Comment: That would be very difficult to achieve, because there are a lot of possibilities depending in what components of the system is down. Can't I use if else nested statement, if system online green, offline red else orange. That kind of logic? Sorry for taking your time and thank you, this is a very valuable learning experience for me.

Comment: No, you don't have to do a if-else check. I have updated my snippet. You can create an object with following outcomes, so once you receive the data, you just need to check the object. You won't be having to use an `if-else`

Comment: I got your point Abin Thaha, but as I mentioned there are a lot of possibilities one I know of and one I don't. So using this approach is quite difficult. There are a lot of systems with a lot of components and variety of down possibilities. That why I though if else would be easier approach.

Comment: Ok, then can you confirm if the it system is down, the status will always have `down` word in it? So as Online and Offline ?

Comment: Yes, it will always have the string ( DOWN: ) then followed by the reason why it is down.

Comment: Ok. Then updated the code in the snippet with a simple if-else condition. This way you won't have to check all the possible scenarios, except you need to check if the status contains the string or not

Comment: You need to check if the particular word is at the index 0 or not

Comment: Please see my codes, I updated my question to include the script.

Comment: Can you share a slice of the data that you are receiving?

Comment: @leethunder, I have updated the answer based on the changes. The thing is you were still updating the classname as the same before and the `if-else` was not doing anything much. Now I have updated the code in the way which will handle all the scenarios.

Comment: Abin Thabha, thank you very much for real man. Actually the code worked fine, it was  fault on my part which I fixed. You do not how much this helped me, thank you dozens. I learned a lot.  Just a quick question, is there a way to add <href> to the status? make it linkable?

Comment: Yeah..add a tag inside the td. That will be fine

Comment: but it is a different url for each system. exmaple, system 1 this url. system 2 that url and so on!!

Comment: Is that url's are available on the API data? Or how do you differentiate the URL's? Based on the status?

Comment: based on the system name and the status, for example, system name 'one' has a specific url. system name 'two', has it's own url and so on.

Comment: Is it possible to get the URL through the API ;/

Comment: Never mind, I figured out how to do it. Thank you very much Abin Thaha, you were a great help for me. God bless you.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really know how this logic could be written in Django but I've tried below.
See if this helps.

```
 <table>
      <tr>
        <th> System Name </th>
        <th> System Status</th>
      </tr>
      </tr>
      {% for i in response %}
    
        {% if i.system_status == 'ONLINE' %}
            {% bgcolor = 'green' %}
        {% elif i.system_status == 'OFFLINE' %}
            {% bgcolor = 'red' %}
        {% else %}
            {% bgcolor = 'orange' %}
        {% endif %}
    
        <tr>
          <td> {{ i.system_name }}</td>
          <td style="background:{{ bgcolor }}"> {{ i.system_status }}</td>
        </tr>
    
      {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Comment: I received this error when I run the code.  "Invalid block tag on line 285: 'bgcolor', expected 'elif', 'else' or 'endif'. Did you forget to register or load this tag?"

Comment: maybe you can try to replace `elseif` on your line number 285 with `elif`

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the other users that it would be easier for you to add class information to the cell in PHP, but if you want to add the classes to the status cell *after* the page has been rendered you can use native JS to iterate over the rows.

```js
// Cache the rows in the table body
const rows = document.querySelectorAll('tbody tr');

// Iterate over them
rows.forEach(row => {

  // Grab the second cell (status)
  const status = Array.from(row.querySelectorAll('td'))[1];

  // And depending on the text content add
  // the appropriate class to the cell
  switch(status.textContent) {
    case 'Online': status.classList.add('online'); break;
    case 'Offline': status.classList.add('offline'); break;
    default: status.classList.add('other'); break;
  }
});
```

```css
.online { background-color: green; }
.offline { background-color: red; }
.other { background-color: orange };
```

```html
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr><th>System Name</th><th>System Status</th></tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>Bob</td><td>Online</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Sally</td><td>Offline</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Steve</td><td>Billy Joel</td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your time to write these code. I never used PHP before. How can I integrate the first block of code in my html page? do I need to add them inside a certain tag??

Comment: Please explain how to use native JS to iterate over the rows. I would love to learn from you, thank you.

Comment: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-run-javascript-from-php/